# development of magnetism in a magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If we cut a magnet, the magnetic field develops. But if we cut it vertically, then will the magnetic field develop?

Comment: What does *"if we cut a magnet the magnetic field develops"* mean? I've never heard the expression of "developing" a magnetic field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iron atoms have a [magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment) so every iron atom behaves like a tiny magnet. The magnetic field from a single atom is tiny, but in a typical ferromagnet, for example iron, the atoms line up their magnetic moments to create small aligned regions called [magnetic domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain). In these domains the fields from all the individual atoms adds up to produce a significant overall magnetic field.

In an unmagnetised piece of iron these magnetic domains are lines up in random directions, so overall their fields cancel out. When you magnetise a piece of iron this lines up all the domains. Now their fields all add up to produce the overall magnetic field.

[image: Magnetic domains]

[Image from Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/ferro.html)

It should now be obvious why cutting a magnetised piece of iron makes two smaller magnets:

[image: Cutting magnet]

It doesn't matter how you cut the magnet or into what shape. As long as the domains stay aligned the resulting pieces of iron will have an overall magnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing really "develop", it's just that the magnetic lines are no longer channeled along the same length and width within a single chunck of material, but 2 smallers. What is apparently "developping" in the air was just confined before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, surely a magnetic field will develop. The cutting magnet vertically will give us two new magnets.